# How to set force SSL encryption on MS SQL server

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, sql-server-2019

I am using MS SQL server 2019 as a database server and i have enabled SSL on SQL server.
I am connecting this SQL server using Java application. So, Java application is client in my case. I have also enabled SSL on client side.
I am able to connect SQL server from client using SSL and without SSL.

My Question is: Is there any way that will be restricted to client(Java application) to only connect using SSL. ?

There must be some configuration that we have to set on database server. So, Client(Java application) can connect using only SSL and if it tries to connect without SSL then database server should abort the connection.

Note: There is a force encryption checkbox in sql server configuration manager that i set to yes but Client still can connect using Non-SSL to database server.

Comment: Does [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52246/ms-sql-server-accepts-non-ssl-connections-even-with-force-encryption-enabled-on) along with [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bde679d9-ff83-4fa7-b402-42e336a97106/force-encryption-on-sql-server-not-working?forum=sqlsecurity) answer your question?

Comment: Have you restarted SQL Server after changing the server config? Does this query show `ecrypt_option` FALSE when the Java app connects without SSL: `SELECT c.session_id, c.client_net_address, c.encrypt_option
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c;`

Comment: @allmhuran - No, I am still not getting that how to reject non-ssl coonection ?

Comment: Per the second link, the server will force the client to use SSL even if the client isn't specifying it. Did you run the query provided by @DanGuzman ?

Comment: @DanGuzman - yes , I have restarted the server. Do i need to run this query on SSMS ?

Comment: You can run the query in SSMS or any other query tool of your choice.

Comment: @DanGuzman - The query is giving true.

Comment: `TRUE` indicates the connection is encrypted as expected. The connection will be rejected outright only if the client API is not capable of TLS. Otherwise, the connection encrypted transparently regardless of whether the client opts in.

Comment: @DanGuzman - I am agree with you but the question is - Connection is Non-ssl (Even i have not imported the cert on client)and it is still connecting the database.

Comment: The key exchange needed for forced transport encryption occurs over the [SQL Server TDS protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b33d45ec-5c8b-4441-bf60-dce9880bd270). The cert does not need to be provisioned in the client. The client can, however, choose whether or not to trust the server certificate for enhanced security. See [Connecting with encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217383/discussion-between-ashish-gupta-and-dan-guzman).